# Best practice for respond_with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, formats

I was wondering which is the best way to handle http errors within respond_with method in rails:

```
respond_to :html, :json

# @my_resources = [] 
def index
  respond_with @my_resources
end
```

This action is responding with http 200 status code. http 204 is "no content" response for the http request, and seems to fit better the correct answer for the original request of the client (with json format). The same behaviour happens with other request and responses.

Linking W3's raccomendation about 204 response code

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html